# VB.net ref value seem to not work

Tags: vb.net

I'm passing a value by reference in this code

```
Private Sub login()

    Dim login As New login(lListClients, bConnected)

    login.ShowDialog()

    login.Dispose()

    If (bConnected = True) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Mokmeuh")
        Button3.Visible = True
        Button4.Visible = True
        Button7.Visible = True
   End If

End Sub
```

And this is the login form

```
Public Class login

    Private lListClients As List(Of Client)
    Private bConnected As Boolean

    Sub New(ByRef lListClients As List(Of Client), ByRef bConnected As Boolean)

        InitializeComponent()
        Me.lListClients = lListClients
        Me.bConnected = bConnected

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim sID = TextBox1.Text, sPassword As String = TextBox2.Text

        For Each cClient As Client In lListClients
            If (Equals(cClient.getID, sID)) Then
                If (Equals(cClient.getPassword, sPassword)) Then
                    bConnected = True
                    MessageBox.Show("Vous êtes connecté vous pouvez continuez")
                    Me.Close()
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Votre ID n'existe pas")
                TextBox1.Clear()
                TextBox2.Clear()
                TextBox1.Focus()
            End If
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        For Each m As Object In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf m Is TextBox Then
                CType(m, TextBox).Text = Nothing
            End If
        Next

        Me.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        TextBox1.Select()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Whenever I launch it the bConnected value in form 1 is always false but in the login form it's true upon destruction so I'm really confuse here I've passed the value by reference it should, when set as true in the login.vb, be true as well in the form1.vb but thw condition `If (bConnected = True)` is never true.

So I need some help thank you

BTW : Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can pass parameters by reference, you cannot store these references. If you want to change the parameter's value, you have to do it in the called method. Otherwise, the runtime cannot ensure that the variable is still alive.

A `List(Of T)` is already a reference type. So it is usually not reasonable to pass this parameter by reference. The variable `lListClients` holds a reference to the actual list object. When passing the variable by value, this reference is copied and passed to the method, resulting in another reference to the very same object. The only reason why you would want to pass this by reference is to change the variable's value from the called method, i.e. assign a new list.

The solution for your problem is quite simple. Create a public property:

```
Public Class login
    Public Property Connected As Boolean

    '...
    Connected = True
    '...
 End Class
```

And use the `login` object to check the value:

```
If login.Connected Then
```

Of course, you should not dispose of the object until you check the value.